# Resolve related entities by unique string column value (SQL, Entity Framework Core)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql, database-design, foreign-keys

While refactoring the code for a project I am currently working on I have been wondering about whether a certain kind of entity insert/update into an SQL database could be done more elegantly.

**TLDR of the module I am working on**: A large amount of data is regularily synchronized from a weakly structured data store (Google Sheets) into a relational database. The source store is database-agnostic and contains no database IDs or foreign keys. The database (EF Core code first) uses standard incremental integer IDs and foreign keys.

**My problem:** The sheets in the Google Sheets largely resemble the database tables. Related entities are referenced by a (by design) unique string value ("Name"). These natural names need to be resolved to the artificial foreign keys when inserting and updating to the database. So far, this process is done by loading the IDs and names of all related entities into memory, finding the matching entity, and then saving the dependant entity with the found foreign keys to the database.

While this process works well, it requires either many more database roundtrips (if the related entity is looked up one by one) or a decent amount of memory to keep all [Name, Id] pairs in memory, and also rendering the database index on the name column useless as the searching is done in memory.

---

As an example, an excerpt from my data model:

Table **Items**, with columns

- Id (Primary Key, unique, clustered index)
- Name (String, unique, indexed)

Table **Locations**, with columns

- Id (Primary Key, unique, clustered index)
- Name (String, unique, indexed)

Table **PlacedItems** (Specific Items, which are placed in a specific location), with columns:

- Id (Primary Key, unique, clustered index)
- LocationId (Foreign Key referencing Locations, indexed)
- ItemId (Foreign Key referencing Items, indexed)

The Google Sheet which I import has the following sheets:

Sheet **items**, with column "Name" (string)

Sheet **locations**, with column "Name" (string)

Sheet **placed_items**, with columns "LocationName" (string) and "ItemName" (string)

---

**My question:**
Assuming, all Items and Locations have been imported, and have been given auto-incremented IDs, how do I most elegantly / efficiently insert all the Placed Items?

The most intrigueing kind of solution would be some way to resolve the Names to Ids entirely on the database, respectively in one round trip, without having to load any item / location data into memory.

To my naïve self it seems like this is a type of problem that I am not the first that tries to solve it, and which has a smart solution already that I am just not seeing yet.

---

Additional points

- I'd like to stick with the artificial IDs in the database. While the strings are unique, they are values designed for being edited by humans and are thus readibility is the prime concern for these strings, and not any kind of efficiency as the DB-generated IDs probably are. When doing reads and any further operations on the data, the IDs are used as primary source for identity and uniqueness of records.
- I don't except Entity Framework Core to have a solution to this problem (but surprise me if it has!), so I am also very interested in solutions with raw SQL, stored procedures and similar

Comment: Suggestion: Just skip the details, put in the query and ask specific questions.  It will help you to get answers quicker

Comment: It appears that you want to `insert into placed_items` from a query that has `join`s between `items`, `locations` and the incoming Placed Items from the sheet. That should be fairly efficient with [covering indexes](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/). If the tables were _quite_ large and the amount of data in each synchronization is relatively quite small it _might_ make sense to `output` lookup tables to use during the duration of loading the third table. Not worth doing until you prove there's a performance problem.